# Is it okay to have two different passports of the same country with same photo but different names?

Tags: passports

I want to issue another passport but i have one already. I need to change my names with the same photo and different age. So is it possible.

Comment: I don't believe any passport lists the age, but they all list the date of birth.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't see how this is a duplicate. Could you explain?

Answer (score 10):

It depends on why you want to do it.  If your current passport is incorrect, you ought to be able to get a new passport with the correct information.  Your current passport will be cancelled when the new one is isssued.

If your current passport is correct, then you won't be able to get a new passport with a different age, because that would be fraudulent.

Answer (score 1):

Age is not listed on the passport, only your date of birth.

If you want to change the date of birth, this means that either there was a clerical error in the previous passport, or some other adjustment has to be made.

Either way, you'll have to provide supporting documents justifying the change; in most countries you cannot have two "active" passports. Once your new passport is issued, the old one is invalidated - you may still keep it (especially if it has a valid visa), but it is no longer valid for travel.

Name change is a bit easier to do - as this is a common change. You just have to get your certificate of name change (generally given by the courts).

In all cases, you need to take your old passport, any required documents, and the passport application form along with any fees to the nearest processing center.

Comment: This is wrong, several countries, including the [US for example](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/obtain-second-passport-legally-61904.html), allow a second active passport for various reasons, including simply frequent travelers who must travel while one of their passport is sent somewhere.

Comment: Or the other common reason being they want to visit both Israel and some other middle-Eastern countries.

Answer (score 0):

The correct/incorrect dichotomy is not exhaustive. Even if your passport *was* correct but you have *changed* your name (for example, you married and decided to take your husband's surname), for USA citizens, you must get a new [passport](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/services/correction.html#Changes).

Comment: True, but the OP also wants to change the age on his passport for some reason. The only reason you could change your age is if it were incorrect on your existing passport, and you'd need proof to demonstrate that. Submitting false documents to change the age on your passport would be illegal pretty much everywhere.