# i need to know more about passport issues

Tags: passports, legal, paperwork

My friend wants to travel but she has a passport with names abcd and a date of birth which males 23yrs.. she wants to make another passport this time with named bc and change to a much younger date of birth but with the same photo. Is it legal, okay or possible?

Comment: You already asked this question:  [is it wrong to have different passports of the same country with same photo but different names?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62188/is-it-wrong-to-have-different-passports-of-the-same-country-with-same-photo-but)  If you want to add details, please edit the existing question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: However, to save you some time, creating your own fake passport, or submitting false information on an application for a real passport, is a crime in every country I know of.

Comment: How many times do you need the internet to tell you that it's not legal to commit passport fraud?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Join the spy agency of your country, and they will issue you another passport with altered details for your work. If you only want to change your age, join the Chinese gymnastics team.

If you have documents to prove that you have another legal name, or that the details on an existing passport are wrong, you should be able to have a passport reissued. Without further details in the question, we can't tell you the exact process.

In all other circumstances that I know of, **what you propose is illegal.**